# My Servlet return a whole page with only one write or one forward (using AJAX call)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I've got an AJAX get function which is calling my Servlet and display the data in an alert.
If I use write or forward function, the result is the same : all my data (+20 000 lines)...

**My Servlet**

```
package com.suptrip.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Alert")
public class Alert extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("OTHERS/alert.html").forward(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("KO");
    }
}
```

**My AJAX**

```
// Load an alert to inform the use that the register form is done with success
    //$('#place-for-alert').load('/Alert', function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){});
    $.get("Alert", function(responseText, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        alert(responseText);
    });
```

There is any error.
Just wrong content given by the Servlet...
Let me know if you need more details/infos !

**Thanks  !**

Comment: It works if I use the "long way" to write the ajax request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I use the "long way" to write the ajax request...

Like this

```
$.ajax({
         url: "Alert",
         //type: "post",
         data: objectArray,
         cache: false,
         success: function(data) {
             $("#place-for-alert").html(data);
         }
    });
```